# How to see the accepted answer % of sites?

Tags: support, site-stats

How can I see the accepted answer % of any Stack Exchange site, including those in beta?

Is there a link?

I would like to find out, for example, out of all questions asked over the last month, how many had

- an accepted answer
- or an answer with say 10 votes

If this isn’t possible, where should I ask?

Answer (score 2):

There is no pre-existing statistics page that shows this. However, you can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) to find out. I wrote [a query to do so](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/766175/accepted-answer-percentage).

<sup>*Psst, there's almost certainly a better way of doing this...*</sup>

```
SELECT
  PostCount,
  WithAccepted,
  WithHighScoreAnswer,
  ROUND((CONVERT(FLOAT, WithAccepted) / PostCount) * 100, 2) AS [Accepted %],
  ROUND((CONVERT(FLOAT, WithHighScoreAnswer) / PostCount) * 100, 2)
    AS [HighScoreAnswer %]
FROM (
  Select
    (select count(*) from Posts) as [PostCount],
    (select count(*) from Posts where AcceptedAnswerId is not null)
     as [WithAccepted],
    (select count(*) from  
      (select count(*) as CountAll from Posts as pq
       inner join Posts as pa on pa.ParentId = pq.Id
       and pa.PostTypeId = 2 group by pq.Id having sum(pa.Score) > 10)
     as HighScoredAnswers)
     as [WithHighScoreAnswer]
) AS Results;
```

Comment: are there any guides/explanations for this that absolute beginners would understand? are there any blogs that has already outline/rank the best stackexchanges based on the results?

Comment: @ambw Visit [the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/766175/accepted-answer-percentage), and scroll down to the results. Those are numbers for Stack Overflow; you can use the site switcher to change sites and get numbers for those.

Comment: yea i was figure that part out due to other experiences/knowledge. but without using the thing you wrote with w/e lang it is, how does anybody else learn all that is needed? including what to write to put into the 'data explorer'? as per the questions in the first comment

Comment: @ambw There is currently no other way to get this data; the only way is through the data explorer. SEDE works by letting you query the database directly in SQL - unfortunately if you don't know SQL, you'll be relying on other users to write queries for you, though there is a [basic tutorial on SQL](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) on SEDE.